# Could not map name UUID | Pacemaker | linux clustering

Tags: centos, centos7, postgresql-9.3, high-availability, pacemaker

I have a Linux Cluster based on Pacemaker(v1.1.18-11) and corosync(v2.4.3-2) setup on Centos 7.2
It is a Two nodes setup with nodes= **DBHA** (master) and **DBFAILOVER** (slave)

I have a resource **Postgresql9** which uses this Resource agent: [pgsql](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ClusterLabs/resource-agents/a6f4ddf76cb4bbc1b3df4c9b6632a6351b63c19e/heartbeat/pgsql) with slight variation

I am using the standard documentation to setup Postgres replication : [PgSQL_Replicated_Cluster](https://wiki.clusterlabs.org/wiki/PgSQL_Replicated_Cluster)

After doing all step for master it still was not becoming master. Following error was shown in */var/log/cluster/corosync.log*

`Could not map name=dbha to a UUID`

After debugging for a bit I found out that following command returns above error:
`/usr/sbin/crm_attribute -l reboot -N "dbha" -n "Postgresql9-status" -v "STOP"`

Where Nodename is calucated by:

`NODENAME=$(ocf_local_nodename | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')`

where ocf_local_nodename() is from ocf-shellfuncs:

```
ocf_local_nodename() {
    # use crm_node -n for pacemaker > 1.1.8
    which pacemakerd > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        local version=$(pacemakerd -$ | grep "Pacemaker .*" | awk '{ print $2 }')
        version=$(echo $version | awk -F- '{ print $1 }')
        ocf_version_cmp "$version" "1.1.8"
        if [ $? -eq 2 ]; then
            which crm_node > /dev/null 2>&1
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                crm_node -n
                return
            fi
        fi
    fi

    # otherwise use uname -n
    uname -n

}
```

I tried running both commands `crm_node -n`  and `uname -n` on DBHA node both return following:
`DBHA`

Also in cibadmin:

`<nodes>
       <node id="2" uname="DBHA">...`

When I Manually run crm_attribute command to set attribute it again returns the same error.

Here is the CIB: [CIB](https://pastebin.com/08w7aQ4B)

Please help

Thanks in advance

NOTE: We have multiple setups on different OS(CENTOS (6.5,6.7,7.2,7.5) Redhat(7.5). We never faced this problem before. Also, the Capital letter (or small letters) in node names never caused any problems before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that, pacemaker change the logic getting node names in `crm_attribute` and left a bug while comparing node names.

This is fixed ([7618c29](https://github.com/ClusterLabs/pacemaker/commit/7618c29761368262fd8d633992816b52755ec028)) in the newer version of the pacemaker. Updating to latest patch fixed it for me.